# Gentoo framebuffer dual monitors

Tags: gentoo, xorg

I have Gentoo and great frame buffer with smaller fonts and great resolution, also I have two monitors.

On both monitors I have same frame buffer. Is it possible to have multiple different frame buffers on two monitors?

Comment: Please split off the second question into a separate post as the two have nothing more in common than that they both deal with framebuffers.

Comment: Not without running two instances of X, I think (twinview  hot seat or the like.)